# Javascript - variable for method name?

Tags: javascript, variables, indirect-objects

How can you reference a javascript object indirectly?

Suppose:

```
<div id="foo" data-munchy="bar" data-crunchy="baz">FooBar</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function() {
    tempVariable = 'munchy';
    console.log(this.dataset.tempVariable);
}
</script>
```

How can I access `this.dataset.{someVariable}`? In this case, `this.dataset.tempVariable`

Is it only possible using `eval` or `window`?

Comment: You want `this.dataset[tempVariable]`.

Comment: `this.dataset[tempVariable]` for your example is the same as `this.dataset.munchy`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @lealceldeiro it appears to be. I don't know why I had so much trouble finding it. Maybe the wording of the question isn't relatable to people who aren't familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use square bracket notation:

```
this.dataset[tempVariable];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: @VictorStoddard - no, that will look for the string `tempVariable` - literally what OP originally had: `this.dataset.tempVariable`

Comment: This is great. I didn't realize they could be accessed both properties and arrays. Thanks, @Kevin.